# Which method is used to run a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I know that `start()` creates a new thread and invokes the `run()` inside that thread and thus thread is executed. But what will be the correct answer of the question...Is it `start()` or is it `run()`? and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "run a thread"? You can start, pause or stop a thread. And then you can run stuff on that thread. But I am not sure what "running a thread" could mean...

Comment: Even I am not getting what it means but the options are those two. It is a multiple choice type question.

Comment: So it’s a mind-guess question rather than a question about Java programming. Then it’s of no use to think about it; instead, the creator of that multiple choice question should be punished.

Comment: @Holger - So, the answer should be *your processor*:P

Comment: @TheLostMind: the problem with these kind of questions is that not only there is no way of giving a different answer, like yours, usually there is also no way of asking back “what do you mean with ‘run’?” or “Do you know that ‘run’ is probably the most overloaded word of the English language?” or well, “What does ‘is used’ mean, do I know the guy your question is about?”

Comment: Stop thinking about Java Threads and start using pooled Executors or Java 8 streams.

Comment: If it's a mutiple choice question, it is a VERY BAD QUESTION.  Threads run methods, not the other way round.

Comment: @Holger - can I give a bounty for comments?? :P... Yes, I agree.. I guess the OP wants to know the difference between `start()` and `run()`..Nevertheless, it is not clear..

Comment: @duffymo, Thread pools are not the answer to every problem.  Thread pools are great when an application needs to use available CPUs to perform short-lived background _tasks_, but sometimes an application needs a special-purpose, long-running thread to wait for some kind of event or input.  The best way to create that kind of thread is by calling ThreadFactory.newThread(r).

Answer (score 5):

You should call `myThread.start()` because `start()` makes a native call to `start0()` which actually creates and executes the `run()` method in a new thread. `run()` will execute the code in the *current* thread.

`run()` method defines *what* is to be executed. `start()` executes `run()` in a *new / separate* thread whereas calling `run()` directly executes `run()` in the *current* thread.

Comment: Ok. So the flow is: start() --> run() --> code in the current thread. 
So, to be more specific, is it not the run() which is running the code of the current thread i.e. the thread?

Comment: @Leo - `run()` is a method which defines *what to execute*. `start()` creates a new thread and executes code inside `run()` *on* the new thread. directly calling `run()` executes code inside `run()` on the *current* thread. What `start()` and in turn `start0()` does internally is too complex..a new java stack, a new PC register(s) , a new native method stack will be created for each thread.. So, yes, the correct order is : `start()` --> some magic here --> `run()` in a *new thread*.

Comment: @Leo, Learn this mantra:  `start()` is provided by the library for your code to call when you want to create a new thread.  `run()` is the method that _you_ provide for the library to call _in_ the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism whereby the run method is invoked on a new thread is extralinguistic: it cannot be represented in terms of Java code. This is the crucial line in the start method:

```
 start0();
```

start0 is a native method whose invocation will:

```
 •cause a new native thread-of-execution to be created;
 •cause the run method to be invoked on that thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Thread.start()` because it only creates a OS thread and assign this job to separate method stack. 
If you call `Thread.run` it will work like a pure java code instead of thread. It will use main thread stack.

Comment: Ok. Forget about Thread.run(). Thread.start() assigns the job to separate method stack. And inside that run() method is exceuted which runs the content of the thread. So, is it not the run() which runs the thread, more specifically? What do you say!

Comment: Ya . Run method has just used the Current thread stack. start method creates a new thread and it has its own stack , then start method execute run method. So Now Current thread is new thread if you are using start method.

Answer (score 0):

thread.start() is the right way. Because internally it actually creates a separate thread i.e a separate call Stack is created and calls thread.run() on that thread.
The JVM creates a separate partition for this thread in the memory to run when you call thread.start() method.

If you do thread.run() it's like a normal method that you execute in single thread environment. Just like `System.out.println("xx");`

**Please read the documentation you'll understand better** [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)